# Form appears after 'Application.CreateForm' step

Tags: delphi

I am working on a project in delphi 2007 (CodeGear RAD Studio). 
There are couple of forms in the application. Thouse forms are created as follows:

```
program MyProgram;

uses
    Forms,
    uMain in 'Source\uMain.pas'                 {MainForm},
    uSettings in 'Source\uSettings.pas'         {fSettings};

{$R *.res}

begin
    Application.Initialize;
    Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
    Application.CreateForm(TSettings, Settings);
    Application.Run;
end.
```

the problem is, that on line `Application.CreateForm(TSettings, Settings);` Settings form  appears (not modal). And the question is why it is happening?.

I know that it is probably not enough information, but I am ready to provide some, if it is needed.

P.S. I am currently re-wrighting programm logic so settings form will be created only before it is about to appear, and after that delete it. Still, I would like to know the answer to this question.

Comment: Agree with Arich 'The

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your settings form's `Visible` property is set to true at design time, and thus it appears as soon as it's created.

Comment: it is so obvious and simple - that's why I missed it! Thank you!

Comment: In modern Delphi versions, secondary auto-created Forms are set to `Visible=False` by default. I do not know if that happens in D2007, or if the OP simply set `Visible=True` and forgot about it.